# Excel VBA: how to specify range as active Table column

Tags: excel, vba

I like to select entire "table column", copy it and then paste it as value on same table column. I like this macro to work on any excel table. I recorded a macro, however, I am unable to change this absolute reference to relative reference:

```
Sub FixedColumn()
ActiveCell.Range("A1:A4950").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

I tried `ActiveCell.EntireColumn` but selects entire column instead of table column.
Also I am unable to use `ActiveCell.ListOjbect` in a right form.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you just want to paste values, you can just do `Range("A1:A4950").Value = Range("A1:A4950").Value`. No need to copy/paste special.  Adjust the range as necessary

Comment: Range("A1:A4950") or any other ranges are calculated formula cells. I just want to make the fixed value cells. I want to have a relative reference macro, which I can run on any calculated table column to make it fixed value column.

Comment: Then just change the range? Or use an inputbox (type 8) that allows the user to select a range. Or create a loop, etc.

Comment: Yes, I can change the range for every new table. However, relative reference macro will be easier to work with. Because I have saved this macro to my hidden personal.xlsb I will try to create inputbox option, however, I don't know how to loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a different solution to define active table column.

1. Select entire `table column` by its `header` and then run following macro
2. `Sub FixedColumn()
        Selection.Copy
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   End Sub`

Thats it, it will change entire `table column` to fixed value column. Save it to `PERSONAL.XLSB` file to use it in any excel file. :)